# Max. revision of data entries in a MySQL multiple COUNT(CASE WHEN THEN END) conditional setting

Tags: mysql, count, conditional-statements, case

Consider the following sample data set:

```
SELECT ID, patID, OP1Datum, OP1OPVerfahren, revision FROM table LIMIT 50;

+----+-------+------------+----------------+----------+
| ID | patID | OP1Datum   | OP1OPVerfahren | revision |
+----+-------+------------+----------------+----------+
|  1 |   649 | 0000-00-00 |              0 |        0 |
|  2 |   649 | 2010-09-23 |              0 |        1 |
|  3 |   649 | 2010-09-23 |              0 |        2 |
|  4 |   649 | 2010-09-23 |              0 |        3 |
|  5 |   649 | 2010-09-23 |              0 |        4 |
|  6 |   649 | 2010-09-23 |              0 |        5 |
|  7 |   649 | 2010-09-23 |              0 |        6 |
|  8 |   649 | 2010-09-23 |              0 |        7 |
|  9 |   649 | 2010-09-23 |              0 |        8 |
| 10 |   649 | 2010-09-23 |              0 |        9 |
| 12 |   673 | 2010-08-16 |              0 |        0 |
| 13 |   676 | 2010-07-05 |              0 |        0 |
| 14 |   649 | 2010-02-17 |              0 |       10 |
| 15 |   649 | 2010-02-17 |              0 |       11 |
| 16 |   676 | 2010-07-05 |              0 |        1 |
| 17 |   718 | 2010-12-01 |              0 |        0 |
| 18 |   720 | 0000-00-00 |              0 |        0 |
| 19 |   720 | 0000-00-00 |              0 |        1 |
| 20 |   649 | 2010-02-17 |              0 |       12 |
| 21 |   649 | 2010-02-17 |              0 |       13 |
| 22 |   649 | 2010-02-17 |              0 |       14 |
| 23 |   649 | 2010-02-17 |              0 |       15 |
| 24 |   649 | 2010-02-17 |              0 |       16 |
| 25 |   719 | 2008-12-03 |              0 |        0 |
| 26 |   719 | 2008-12-03 |              0 |        1 |
| 27 |   721 | 2008-12-03 |              0 |        1 |
| 28 |   649 | 2010-02-16 |              0 |       17 |
| 29 |   649 | 2010-02-16 |              0 |       18 |
| 30 |   720 | 2011-02-03 |              0 |        2 |
| 31 |   720 | 2011-02-03 |              0 |        3 |
| 32 |   720 | 2011-02-03 |              0 |        4 |
| 33 |   720 | 2011-02-03 |              0 |        5 |
| 34 |   720 | 2011-02-03 |              0 |        6 |
| 35 |   676 | 2010-07-05 |              0 |        2 |
| 36 |   718 | 2010-12-01 |              0 |        1 |
| 37 |   719 | 2008-12-03 |              0 |        2 |
| 38 |   721 | 2008-12-03 |              0 |        2 |
| 39 |   649 | 2010-02-16 |              0 |       19 |
| 40 |   673 | 2010-08-16 |              0 |        1 |
| 41 |   694 | 2011-02-16 |              0 |        0 |
| 42 |   649 | 2010-02-16 |              0 |       20 |
| 43 |   649 | 2010-10-23 |              0 |       21 |
| 44 |   649 | 2010-02-16 |              0 |       22 |
| 45 |   649 | 2010-02-16 |              0 |       23 |
| 46 |   649 | 2010-02-16 |              0 |       24 |
| 47 |   724 | 2011-03-02 |              0 |        0 |
| 48 |   724 | 2011-03-02 |              0 |        1 |
| 49 |   694 | 2011-02-16 |              0 |        1 |
| 50 |   694 | 2011-02-16 |              0 |        2 |
| 51 |   649 | 2010-02-16 |              0 |       25 |
+----+-------+------------+----------------+----------+
```

patID 649, for example, shows 26 revisions of the data record, i. e. this record has been saved 26 times.

I want to show only the rows with the individually highest revision number. So the desired data set would like this:

```
+----+-------+------------+----------------+----------+
| ID | patID | OP1Datum   | OP1OPVerfahren | revision |
+----+-------+------------+----------------+----------+
|  1 |   649 | 0000-00-00 |              0 |       25 |
|  2 |   673 | 2010-08-16 |              0 |        1 |
|  3 |   676 | 2010-07-05 |              0 |        2 |
|  4 |   718 | 2010-12-01 |              0 |        1 |
|  5 |   719 | 2008-12-03 |              0 |        2 |
|  6 |   720 | 2011-02-03 |              0 |        6 |
|  7 |   721 | 2008-12-03 |              0 |        2 |
|  8 |   724 | 2011-03-02 |              0 |        1 |
|  9 |   694 | 2011-02-16 |              0 |        2 |
+----+-------+------------+----------------+----------+
```

Has anyone an idea of how to handle this?

Comment: Not really relevant but in MySQL you can simplify `COUNT(case when op.OP1OPVerfahren = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)` to `SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 0)` as MySQL treats boolean expressions as either 1 or 0 in a numeric context

Comment: Thank you, @Nick, but still leaves the revision issue unsolved.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Also, does it make sense that the same method can appear in two different columns ??!

Comment: Data display is not the issue. A basic MySQL table with the data may look like this: PatientID, RecordID, [many other fields], OP1OPVerfahren, [many other fields], revision. So a result set could look like this: 1,1,0,0; the next one is 1,2,0,1, then the third one 1,3,1,2 (major change concerning OP1OPVerfahren content), and the last one 1,4,0,3. I want to extract only the one with the highest revision number which is "3" here. I do not understand your comment "the same method can appear in two different columns", could you please explain what you are referring to?

Comment: "Fobi / Capella Bypass" and "Larrad" both equal 12. Display may not be the issue, but porting issues of display to application code would considerably simplify the problem

Comment: Ah, now I know what you mean. Yes, they both wrongly point to 12, but this is a minor flaw I have already fixed in the sql query code the PHP application scripts, but thank you nevertheless for paying attention to this. What do you say about the revision - let's ust focus on this sql query and not the PHP code.

Comment: Which circumstances?

Comment: Two circumstances: 1. the fact that you already have application code, and you prefer to carry out a huge, unwieldy, and unscalable pivot in SQL and 2. how well or badly this data set is documented is not the question here'

Comment: Okay, @Strawberry, then please indicate what you want or need to go on. The MySQL sql query is a query which shall give me a quick overview over data results before I put it into the PHP framework. With the documentation of the data set I meant the data the users are documenting - they can be good so that no further changes are needed and, thus, the revision numbers remain small, or they can be bad - with inexperienced users - so that the revision numbers are high - that is what I meant.

Comment: Yes, I have prepared it. I have posted it as an edit under yours.

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: I have seen it and will try it oin a bit, but for the INSERT statement you have left the rev field away?

Comment: And: Could you please explain the JOIN content? Why MIN(id) id, why COUNT(*)-1 and what do both mean?

Comment: Last question: How do I count the results now in relation to the number of OP1OPVerfahren?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,patient_id INT NOT NULL
,dt DATE
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
( 1,649,'0000-00-00'),
( 2,649,'2010-09-23'),
( 3,649,'2010-09-23'),
( 4,649,'2010-09-23'),
( 5,649,'2010-09-23'),
( 6,649,'2010-09-23'),
( 7,649,'2010-09-23'),
( 8,649,'2010-09-23'),
( 9,649,'2010-09-23'),
(10,649,'2010-09-23'),
(12,673,'2010-08-16'),
(13,676,'2010-07-05'),
(14,649,'2010-02-17'),
(15,649,'2010-02-17'),
(16,676,'2010-07-05'),
(17,718,'2010-12-01'),
(18,720,'0000-00-00'),
(19,720,'0000-00-00'),
(20,649,'2010-02-17'),
(21,649,'2010-02-17'),
(22,649,'2010-02-17'),
(23,649,'2010-02-17'),
(24,649,'2010-02-17'),
(25,719,'2008-12-03'),
(26,719,'2008-12-03'),
(27,721,'2008-12-03'),
(28,649,'2010-02-16'),
(29,649,'2010-02-16'),
(30,720,'2011-02-03'),
(31,720,'2011-02-03'),
(32,720,'2011-02-03'),
(33,720,'2011-02-03'),
(34,720,'2011-02-03'),
(35,676,'2010-07-05'),
(36,718,'2010-12-01'),
(37,719,'2008-12-03'),
(38,721,'2008-12-03'),
(39,649,'2010-02-16'),
(40,673,'2010-08-16'),
(41,694,'2011-02-16'),
(42,649,'2010-02-16'),
(43,649,'2010-10-23'),
(44,649,'2010-02-16'),
(45,649,'2010-02-16'),
(46,649,'2010-02-16'),
(47,724,'2011-03-02'),
(48,724,'2011-03-02'),
(49,694,'2011-02-16'),
(50,694,'2011-02-16'),
(51,649,'2010-02-16');
```

A query:

```
SELECT x.*
     , y.rev 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MIN(id) id, COUNT(*)-1 rev FROM my_table GROUP BY patient_id ) y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
 ORDER 
    BY id;
+----+------------+------------+-----+
| id | patient_id | dt         | rev |
+----+------------+------------+-----+
|  1 |        649 | 0000-00-00 |  25 |
| 12 |        673 | 2010-08-16 |   1 |
| 13 |        676 | 2010-07-05 |   2 |
| 17 |        718 | 2010-12-01 |   1 |
| 18 |        720 | 0000-00-00 |   6 |
| 25 |        719 | 2008-12-03 |   2 |
| 27 |        721 | 2008-12-03 |   1 |
| 41 |        694 | 2011-02-16 |   2 |
| 47 |        724 | 2011-03-02 |   1 |
+----+------------+------------+-----+
```

Comment: Could you please explain the JOIN content? Why MIN(id) id, why COUNT(*)-1 and what do both mean? And how do I count the results now in relation to the number of OP1OPVerfahren?

Comment: It is not easy to find myself at place in the nth formalism on Stackoverflow ... surely one needs a standardized way to present one's code issues here, but comments, for instance, can only be edited for a period of 5 min etc. Please get back to me as soon as you read this - a @Strawberry at the beginning of a comment is automatically deleted, BTW.

Comment: Your desired result set suggests that you want the first occurrence of each user, together with the number of revisions. `MIN(id)` gets the first occurrence of each user. `COUNT(*)-1` gets the number of revisions - your revisions column is redundant, so I got rid of it.

Comment: Yes, I have got it. Now I clearly see the way to extract the **patients** as related to their very first (MIN(ID)) or last (MAX(ID)) data set revisions. But what I need now is exactly this information - "identify the valid operation by the highst number of revision" - counted for the various numbers of operations existing (from OP1OPVerfahren = "0" to ... = "99" which leads me to the original SELECT(COUNT ...) query: How can I integrate the now existing information into that counting process, strictly all within an SQL query? Should I formulate a new question?

Comment: Yes. You should formulate a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer; too long for a comment...

Here's what I thinks a valid approach to the first part of the problem...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS method;

CREATE TABLE method
(method_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,method VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO method VALUES 
(  1,  "Keine Operation"),
(  2,  "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)"),
(  3,  "Gastric Banding"),
(  4,  "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass"),
(  5,  "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass banded"),
(  6,  "Scopinaro"),
(  7,  "Duodenal Switch (DS)"),
(  8,  "Sleeve Resection"),
(  9,  "Gastric Pacemaker"),
( 10,  "Billroth II"),
( 12,  "Gastroplasty"),
( 13,  "Fobi / Capella Bypass"),
( 14,  "Larrad"),
( 15,  "Santoro"),
( 16,  "DJB"),
( 17,  "TOGA"),
( 18,  "Endobarrier"),
( 19,  "Gastric Plication"),
( 20,  "Stomaphyx"),
( 21,  "Omega Loop Bypass"),
( 22,  "Omega Loop Bypass banded"),
( 23,  "Long Limb Bypass"),
( 24,  "Distal Very Long Gastric Bypass (Thurnheer)"),
( 25,  "Endoscopic Sclerosation"),
( 26,  "Swedish Adjustable Gastric Bypass (SAGB)"),
( 27,  "Vertical Banded Gastroplasty (VBG)"),
( 28,  "Plastic Abdominal Wall Reconstruction (PAWR)"),
( 29,  "Inner Hernia Repair"),
( 30,  "Single Anastomosis Duodeno-Ileal Bypass with Sleeve Gastrectomy (SADI-S)"),
(100,  "Anderes OP-Verfahren");

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS therapy;

CREATE TABLE therapy
(therapy_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,method_id INT NOT NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO therapy (SELECT NULL,1+(RAND()*30),'2015-01-01' + INTERVAL RAND()*100 DAY);
INSERT INTO therapy SELECT NULL,1+(RAND()*30),'2015-01-01' + INTERVAL RAND()*100 DAY FROM therapy; -- Repeat this line a few times...

SELECT m.*
     , COUNT(t.therapy_id) total 
  FROM method m 
  LEFT 
  JOIN therapy t 
    ON t.method_id = m.method_id 
 GROUP 
    BY m.method_id;
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| method_id | method                                                                   | total |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|         1 | Keine Operation                                                          |    38 |
|         2 | Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)                                    |    79 |
|         3 | Gastric Banding                                                          |    72 |
|         4 | Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass                                                 |    73 |
|         5 | Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass banded                                          |    59 |
|         6 | Scopinaro                                                                |    66 |
|         7 | Duodenal Switch (DS)                                                     |    58 |
|         8 | Sleeve Resection                                                         |    67 |
|         9 | Gastric Pacemaker                                                        |    64 |
|        10 | Billroth II                                                              |    67 |
|        12 | Gastroplasty                                                             |    55 |
|        13 | Fobi / Capella Bypass                                                    |    68 |
|        14 | Larrad                                                                   |    61 |
|        15 | Santoro                                                                  |    69 |
|        16 | DJB                                                                      |    69 |
|        17 | TOGA                                                                     |    60 |
|        18 | Endobarrier                                                              |    67 |
|        19 | Gastric Plication                                                        |    77 |
|        20 | Stomaphyx                                                                |    65 |
|        21 | Omega Loop Bypass                                                        |    86 |
|        22 | Omega Loop Bypass banded                                                 |    83 |
|        23 | Long Limb Bypass                                                         |    69 |
|        24 | Distal Very Long Gastric Bypass (Thurnheer)                              |    58 |
|        25 | Endoscopic Sclerosation                                                  |    67 |
|        26 | Swedish Adjustable Gastric Bypass (SAGB)                                 |    69 |
|        27 | Vertical Banded Gastroplasty (VBG)                                       |    71 |
|        28 | Plastic Abdominal Wall Reconstruction (PAWR)                             |    69 |
|        29 | Inner Hernia Repair                                                      |    72 |
|        30 | Single Anastomosis Duodeno-Ileal Bypass with Sleeve Gastrectomy (SADI-S) |    77 |
|       100 | Anderes OP-Verfahren                                                     |     0 |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

The rest of this part of the problem is a display issue, more properly handled in application code.

For the next part of the problem, we'd need to see an MCVE, together with a desired result (See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)
). Obviously, don't use real patient data for that!

Comment: I have prepared a file with all content; it has 3.000 result lines from the fields id, patID, OP1Datum, OP1OPVerfahren and revision; how can I "upload" it or otherwise make it visible?

Comment: I have edited my question and inserted a real data result set (50 lines). Is that enough for an idea?

Comment: Sorry, @Strawberry, slowly I am losing the grip on what shall be done. I **have** posted a question - this question emcompasses with my literary words what I do not understand how to do - I have posted a result set of the first 50 lines of my MySQL table in a different SQL query to further explain the concept of my revision field - I have followed your code sample and realized it on my server and - obviously wrongly - posted the results under your answer. I do no longer know what I am supposed to do now or where you want to lead me to.

Comment: Gotcha. Wait, I'll refine my question.

Comment: Done - I have changed the question.

Comment: Could you please explain the JOIN content? Why MIN(id) id, why COUNT(*)-1 and what do both mean? And how do I count the results now in relation to the number of OP1OPVerfahren?

Comment: It is not easy to find myself at place in the nth formalism on Stackoverflow ... surely one needs a standardized way to present one's code issues here, but comments, for instance, can only be edited for a period of 5 min etc. Please get back to me as soon as you read this - a @Strawberry at the beginning of a comment is automatically deleted, BTW.